# Where is an API located in the MVC architecture?

Tags: model-view-controller

To which part of the MVC pattern belongs an API? Am I right with the assumption that it belongs to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm talking about an application which provides an API to access data from the model.

Then these are conceptually different things. You are offering an API on your server (let's assume REST based); the API here is *your server and the software which runs on it.* That software may internally be built using an MVC pattern. An API request is handled by a controller, a model, and the response is output by the view. An API request uses all three parts of MVC. "The API" is what your software looks like "from outside".

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the server you are connecting to through the API as a data storage, the API is a layer between the data storage and the controller/view.

In MVC architecture, the model contains a data storage with a service that controller or view can access to obtain the data.

In this case, API is the service, so I would say it is part of the model.